# Is it possible to have a separate scroll area inside a DraggableScrollableSheet?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a bottom sheet where only the top area of the sheet can be dragged to expand the sheet. The bottom area consists of a list which is scrolled separately, thus it should be scrollable while the child-size of the DraggableScrollableSheet remains the same. This image show what i'm trying to accomplish

[image]

With the following code I managed to create a top section that sticks to the top and a bottom section that is scrollable. However, the top section can't be dragged to expand the sheet.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<CompetitionCubit, Competition>(
        builder: (context, state) {
      return DraggableScrollableSheet(
        builder: (context, scrollController) {
          return Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                topRight: Radius.circular(20),
              ),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  blurRadius: 10.0,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                // Top area content
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Draggable top section',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                  ),
                ),
                const Divider(
                  thickness: 1,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                // Bottom area content
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 50,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text('Item $index'),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    },
);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, since is not a common behavior there is not an easy way to do that, but try this code, as you can see there are some items that are "duplicated"

```dart
class DragabbleSheetExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const DragabbleSheetExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<DragabbleSheetExample> createState() => _DragabbleSheetExampleState();
}

class _DragabbleSheetExampleState extends State<DragabbleSheetExample> {
  bool isDragableFull = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: NotificationListener<DraggableScrollableNotification>(
          onNotification: (DraggableScrollableNotification dSNotification) {
            if (!isDragableFull && dSNotification.extent >= 1) {
              isDragableFull = true;
            } else if (isDragableFull && dSNotification.extent <= 0.3) {
              isDragableFull = false;
            }
            setState(() {});

            return true;
          },
          child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
            initialChildSize: 0.3,
            minChildSize: 0.3,
            maxChildSize: 1,
            builder: (context, scrollController) {
              return Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      blurRadius: 10.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                // Parent scroller added
                child: (isDragableFull)
                    ? Column(
                        children: [
                          const Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                            child: Text(
                              'Draggable top section',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const Divider(
                            thickness: 1,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: 50,
                              controller: scrollController,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return ListTile(
                                  title: Text('Item $index'),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    : SingleChildScrollView(
                        // Controller from DraggableScrollableSheet added to SingleChildScrollView
                        controller: scrollController,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            // Top area content
                            const Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                              child: Text(
                                'Draggable top section',
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const Divider(
                              thickness: 1,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),

                            // List view updated

                            SizedBox(
                              height: 300,
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: 50,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return ListTile(
                                    title: Text('Item $index'),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This suggestion does not work, dragging in the list should not expand the sheet and the top section should always be visible above the list.

Comment: Sorry, could you try the updated answer please